# How WhatsApp designed send image preview with edittext UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

[image]
Whats app send image preview UI design I need similar to this UI, can someone help how this can be achieved

Below is the XML I have designed but send button is moving when edit text is growing while typing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".ui.AttachmentSendPreviewActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_attachment_send_preview">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_send_attachment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorBlackDull"
        android:padding="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextCaption"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Add a caption"

            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton

        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSend"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"

        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button_bg"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.97"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.95" />




</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

when edit text grows multiple lines send button is not moving accordingly can someone help how to give constraint to send button to move when edit text grows

Imageview should not be scrolled up only edit text need to be scrolled up when keyboard pops how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: why do you ask **us** how **they** did it? Also what exactly is a problem for you to design similar UI?

Comment: I have updated my question please see.Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageViewPreview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCaption"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:paddingEnd="75dp"
        android:hint="Add a caption"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorHint="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSend"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/editTextCaption"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/editTextCaption"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

try this and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You can improve this answer by providing some explanation of how this code works

Comment: @Aleks G, I have connected bottom and top of ImageButton to top of EditText that's it.  app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/editTextCaption"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/editTextCaption"

Comment: Perfect its working button moving along with Edittext now but i achieved same with Coordinator layout now.Thanks for your reply .and I want image view to be fixed when keyboard pops in edit text like whats app but in my layout imageview too scrolling up along with edittext

Comment: @MustafaBohra can you help on how to stop scrolling image view along with edittext i want the edit text to be moved over the image view when keyboard opens

Comment: @kondal the layout i provided in above answer does not move imageview with edittext i think

Comment: @MustafaBohra actually i kept that layout in coordinator layout so when keyboard opens it moves up but i need only edit text moved over the image view

Comment: @kondal please provide your layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183881/discussion-between-kondal-and-mustafa-bohra).